# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Obj') React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm retrieving a JSON object using React Native Fetch and my goal is to render it as a dropdown on screen. However, before working on the rendering part, I get this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Obj') React Native" on componentDidMount() and I am not sure what the issue is.

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?_limit=10")  // **Api for fetching**
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        var count = Object.keys(responseJson.message.Obj).length;
        let drop_down = [];
        for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
          console.log(responseJson.message.Obj[i].title) // I need to add 
          drop_down.push({ value: responseJson.message.Obj[i].title }); // Creating array of data
        }
        this.setState({ drop_down }); // Set the new state
      })
      .catch(error =>console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check what you are getting in `responseJson.message` it seems to be not present, thus the error

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Obj')` means whatever you call `.Obj` upon is undefined. In your case it is `responseJson.message` is undefined. So every time you see this message, you need to trace up two layer to debug. In your case check what is `responseJson`

Since you are fetching from a public API, I did a quick call in my browser using the following debug code:

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?_limit=10")
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then((responseJson) => {console.log(responseJson)})
```

And I see the following in my console:

```
0: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
1: {userId: 1, id: 2, title: 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui', completed: false}
2: {userId: 1, id: 3, title: 'fugiat veniam minus', completed: false}
3: {userId: 1, id: 4, title: 'et porro tempora', completed: true}
4: {userId: 1, id: 5, title: 'laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum', completed: false}
5: {userId: 1, id: 6, title: 'qui ullam ratione quibusdam voluptatem quia omnis', completed: false}
6: {userId: 1, id: 7, title: 'illo expedita consequatur quia in', completed: false}
7: {userId: 1, id: 8, title: 'quo adipisci enim quam ut ab', completed: true}
8: {userId: 1, id: 9, title: 'molestiae perspiciatis ipsa', completed: false}
9: {userId: 1, id: 10, title: 'illo est ratione doloremque quia maiores aut', completed: true}
```

What this means is that your `responseJson` is already the data array that you want to work on. No need to do further modification, also there is no such key as `responseJson.message` nor `responseJson.message.Obj`.

Based on your code, I think this is what you would need:

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?_limit=10")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    const drop_down = responseJson.map(todo => { 
        return { value: todo.title }
    });
    this.setState({ drop_down });
  })
  .catch(error =>console.log(error))
```

Also you can refer to the API's guide which walk you through what the data looks like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/